# Laravel migration references between tables

Tags: php, mysql, migration, laravel-5

I've read laravel eloquent relationship & database migration docs, but I can't understand one thing. We can create a relationship between two tables through creating migration file like:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('keywords', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('keyword_group_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('keyword_group_id')->references('id')->on('keyword_groups')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

And then, after **php artisan migrate** command we got two connected with **one to many** relation tables.
On the other side docs describes process of *creating* relations between two Eloquents. In my case it looks like:

```
class Keyword extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = array('name');

    public function keywordGroup()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\KeywordGroup');
    }
}

class KeywordGroup extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = array('name');

    public function keywords()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Keyword');
    }
}
```

But if I comment string of code, that make relation between tables in migration file, this two *connection* functions in model classes doesn't creat any relationship.
Can you please explain me for what we need to write that methods inside model classes? **keywordGroup** & **keywords**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The migrations create your database structure, if you create a foreign key here a relation will be added in your database itself.

The relations you create in your model have no effect on the database itself, they are only used to make it easy to load data from different tables in code. These will work wether or not you have created foreign keys in your database.